Asymptotic equivalent of sequence defined by a recursion relation.
For the study of a termination speed of a recursive algorithm of mine, I would like to have more precise result on the following sequence:
$$0< a_0 = a< 4 \qquad \text{and} \qquad a_{k+1} = \frac{a_k}{2 + \sqrt{4-a_k}}.$$
I already know that $a_k$ should behave somewhat like $\frac{a}{4^k}$ and has at least geometric convergence speed to $0$. I have small hopes for a closed form but I know (it has been a long time) that I used to solve some problems about finding asymptotical equivalents to such sequences. Here is what I have so far:
$$\begin{align*}
a_{k+1} &= \frac{a_k}{2 + \sqrt{4-a_k}} = \frac{a_k}{2 + 2-\frac{a_k}{4} + \mathcal O (a_k^2)} = \frac{a_k}{4} \left(1 + \frac{a_k}{16} + \mathcal O (a_k^2) \right)\\
&= \frac{a_k}{4} + \frac{a_k^2}{64} + \mathcal O(a_k^3)
\end{align*}$$
From now on I'm stuck, I thought about similar processes for $1/a_k$ but did not manage to go further. I also tried to recognise some newton method-like sequence but it does not seem to be related.
I also have
$$4^{k+1} a_{k+1} = 4^k a_k ( 1 +a_k/16 + \mathcal O (a_k^2)) $$
So since $a_k \le a \cdot \lambda^{k}$ with $0<\lambda < 1/2$, I have the convergence of the infinite product $( 1 +a_k/16 + \mathcal O (a_k^2))$ which means
$$a_k = \Theta ( 4^{-k})$$
and even $a_k \sim c \cdot 4^{-k}$ if I am not mistaken. But I would like to find $c$ or at least bind it.
I guess this is probably very classic and easy but I can't recover my results at all, so any help is welcome.

As mentionned in the comments, we have $a_{k+1} = f(a_k)$ with $f(x) = \frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4-x}} = 2 - \sqrt{4-x}$ so since $f$ is convex, a Banach fixed point theorem tells me that
$$a_{n+k} \le f'(a_k)^n \cdot a_k = \frac{a_k}{2^n\sqrt{4-a_k}^n}$$
Combining these results, I manage to obtain
$$a_{n+1} < 2^{\frac{1}{2 \ln(2)} - 2n}$$
With the addition of the last results in my answer to this problem (which uses the algorithm), I know that
$$ \frac{\pi e }{8}\le c\le 2^{\frac{1}{2 \ln(2)}+2}$$

Just mentioning that the recursion can also be written as $a_{k+1} = 2 - \sqrt{4-a_k}$.

@MartinR yeah I just figured it 1 mn ago, I was on my way to modify it

Your $c$ will depend on $a_0$: $$
c = a_0 \prod\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{4}{{2 + \sqrt {4 - a_n } }}} .
$$

@Gary yes I already figured that result but did not detail it

With $c$ given as above, it seems that there is any asymptotic expansion of the form $$
a_n  \sim c4^{ - n}  - \frac{1}{{12}}(c4^{ - n} )^2  + \frac{1}{{360}}(c4^{ - n} )^3  +  \ldots , .
$$

@Gary Nice! How did you do it ? Did you study $a_n-c4^{-n}$?

I looked for a formal power series that satisfies $$F\left( {\frac{x}{4}} \right) = 2 - \sqrt {4 - F(x)}. $$ I found $F(x)=x-\frac{x^2}{12}+\frac{x^3}{360}+\ldots$. Assuming this converges for $|x|<4$ and is injective, we can set $c = F^{ - 1} (a_0 )$ and $a_n  = F(c4^n )$.

Oh smart! I forgot about this technique

I meant $a_n=F(c 4^{-n})$ of course.

It's evident that $0<a_n\le 2$ for $n \ge 1$. Let's denote $a_n = 4\sin^2(b_n)$ for $b_n \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$, then
$$\begin{align}
&\iff a_{n+1} = 2 -\sqrt{4 - a_n}\\
&\iff 4 \sin^2(b_{n+1}) = 2 - 2\cos(b_n)\\
&\iff \cos(2b_{n+1}) = \cos(b_n) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
As $b_n \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$ we have then $2b_n \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ and so
$$(1) \iff 2b_{n+1} = b_n \iff b_n = \frac{b^0}{2^n}$$
The closed-form formula of $a_n$ is then
$$\color{red}{a_n = 4\sin^2 \left(\frac{\arcsin(\sqrt{a_0/4})}{2^n}  \right)}$$
and it's easy to deduce the assymptics of $a_n$ from its closed-form formula!

Wow, thanks I had no hope for a closed formula,I'm realising just now that I had the solution just under my eyes since the formula comes from arc distances on the curve.

I meant sphere not curve

@julio_es_sui_glace You're welcome!

Define the function $F: [0, \pi^2] \to [0, 4]$ by
$$  
F(x) = 4 \sin^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right).  
$$
This function satisfies the functional equation
$$  
F\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) = 2 - \sqrt{4 - F(x)}.  
$$
Now, fix $a$ with $0 \leq a \leq 4$, and let $c = F^{-1}(a)$. Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$ defined by $a_n = F(c \cdot 4^{-n})$. This sequence satisfies
$$  
a_0 = a, \quad a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2 + \sqrt{4 - a_n}} = 2 - \sqrt{4 - a_n}, \quad n\ge 0.
$$
Expanding $F$ around the origin yields the asymptotic expansion
$$  
a_n = 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{k + 1} \frac{{\left( {c4^{ - n} } \right)^k }}{{(2k)!}}} 
=c4^{-n} - \frac{1}{12}(c4^{-n})^2 + \frac{1}{360}(c4^{-n})^3 + \cdots.  
$$

Thanks for the detailed post, I guess this series expansion should match the answer by NN2

Yes, the solution is equivalent to the one given by NN2 (which was posted after mine).

Yes I know, I accepted the other since we directly have a closed form and it fits my problem very well. Thanks for the good work
